# Are there titles that require not fleeing battles?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

Are there titles that require not fleeing battles?

I know Genis has the one about not using Gels until a certain point...

I'm trying to see what the hardest challenge to get as many titles in one run is... And I fled battles. Now I'm wondering if I should be concerned...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Ctrl + F search of the words "flee", "fled" and "running" [on this Steam guide of "Complete Title List"](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=644078516) only reveals one title that says:

> "Clear the battle with Yuan without running away from battles up to that point", and it's a title for Lloyd.

On another website, they say this instead:

> "Don't escape from battles until Yuan is defeated at the Tethe'alla Renegade Base"

So it's quite clear that you can't run until a specific part of the game if you want that one title.

In case of doubt, you can use this [save checker](http://rngeoff.com/symphoniasaveviewer) to have a look at your saves.

Your files are at, if you're on PC: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\[USERID]\372360\remote

Comment: Hmm... I hope I'm mixing up my memories when I ran just so I could reload, and actually didn't run away in my canonical events... ... ... There's no way to check if I ran or not, is there?

Comment: @Malady You can try your luck with this save checker. It allowed me to know which character liked Lloyd the most, but I don't remember exactly what it gives: http://rngeoff.com/symphoniasaveviewer

Comment: It does reveal info! And everyone's Current / Max Battles, is 100%... So I... Aha! It's under the "PC SAVE" section, for some reason. Escapes is 0!

Comment: @Malady Remember to mark this answer as accepted if it did answer your question, this way any future reader knows that you found a solution to your question.